# AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate drop frames using CIFilters for video filtering

Tags: ios, swift, video, avcapturesession, cifilter

I have very strange case where AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate drops frames if I use 13 different filter chains. Let me explain:

I have CameraController setup, nothing special, here is my delegate method:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        if !paused {

            if connection.output?.connection(with: .audio) == nil {
                //capture video

                // my try to avoid "Out of buffers error", no luck ;(
                lastCapturedBuffer = nil
                let err = CMSampleBufferCreateCopy(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, sampleBufferOut: &lastCapturedBuffer)
                if err == noErr {

                }

                connection.videoOrientation = .portrait

                // getting image
                let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(lastCapturedBuffer!)
                // remove if any
                CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

                // captured - is just ciimage property
                captured = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)
                //remove if any
                CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!,CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
                //CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, .readOnly)

                // transform image to targer resolution
                let srcWidth = CGFloat(captured.extent.width)
                let srcHeight = CGFloat(captured.extent.height)

                let dstWidth: CGFloat = ConstantsManager.shared.k_video_width
                let dstHeight: CGFloat = ConstantsManager.shared.k_video_height

                let scaleX = dstWidth / srcWidth
                let scaleY = dstHeight / srcHeight

                var transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: scaleX, y: scaleY)
                captured = captured.transformed(by: transform).cropped(to: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: dstWidth, height: dstHeight))
                // mirror for front camera
                if front {
                    var t = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
                    t = t.translatedBy(x: -ConstantsManager.shared.k_video_width, y: 0)
                    captured = captured.transformed(by: t)
                }

                // video capture logic
                let writable = canWrite()

                if writable,
                    sessionAtSourceTime == nil {
                    sessionAtSourceTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(lastCapturedBuffer!)
                    videoWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: sessionAtSourceTime!)
                }

                if writable, (videoWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {
                    videoWriterInput.append(lastCapturedBuffer!)
                }

                // apply effect in realtime <- here is problem. If I comment next line, it will be fixed but effect will n't be applied
                captured = FilterManager.shared.applyFilterForCamera(inputImage: captured)

                // current frame in case user wants to save image as photo
                self.capturedPhoto = captured

                // sent frame to Camcoder view controller
                self.delegate?.didCapturedFrame(frame: captured)
            } else {
                // capture sound
                let writable = canWrite()
                if writable, (audioWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {
                    //print("write audio buffer")
                    audioWriterInput?.append(lastCapturedBuffer!)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // paused
        }
    }
```

I also implemented didDrop delegate method, here is how I figure out why it drops frames:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didDrop sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        print("did drop")
        var mode: CMAttachmentMode = 0
        let reason = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, key: kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_DroppedFrameReason, attachmentModeOut: &mode)
        print("reason \(String(describing: reason))") // Optional(OutOfBuffers)
    }
```

So I did it like a pro and just commented parts of code to find where is the problem. So, it here:

```
captured = FilterManager.shared.applyFilterForCamera(inputImage: captured)
```

FilterManager - is singleton, here is called func:

```
func applyFilterForCamera(inputImage: CIImage) -> CIImage {
        return currentVsFilter!.apply(sourceImage: inputImage)
    }
```

currentVsFilter is object of VSFilter type - here is example of one:

```
import Foundation
import AVKit

class TestFilter: CustomFilter {

    let _name = "Тестовый Фильтр"
    let _displayName = "Test Filter"

    var tempImage: CIImage?
    var final: CGImage?

    override func name() -> String {
        return _name
    }

    override func displayName() -> String {
        return _displayName
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("Test Filter init")

        // setup my custom kernel filter
        self.noise.type = GlitchFilter.GlitchType.allCases[2]
    }

    // this returns composition for playback using AVPlayer
    override func composition(asset: AVAsset) -> AVMutableVideoComposition {
        let composition = AVMutableVideoComposition(asset: asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { request in
            let inputImage = request.sourceImage.cropped(to: request.sourceImage.extent)
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                let output = self.apply(sourceImage: inputImage, forComposition: true)
                request.finish(with: output, context: nil)
            }
        })
        let size = FilterManager.shared.cropRectForOrientation().size

        composition.renderSize = size
        return composition
    }

    // this returns actual filtered CIImage, used for both AVPlayer composition and realtime camera
    override func apply(sourceImage: CIImage, forComposition: Bool = false) -> CIImage {

        // rendered text
        tempImage = FilterManager.shared.textRenderedImage()

        // some filters chained one by one
        self.screenBlend?.setValue(tempImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        self.screenBlend?.setValue(sourceImage, forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)

        self.noise.inputImage = self.screenBlend?.outputImage
        self.noise.inputAmount = CGFloat.random(in: 1.0...3.0)

        // result
        tempImage = self.noise.outputImage

        // correct crop
        let rect = forComposition ? FilterManager.shared.cropRectForOrientation() : FilterManager.shared.cropRect
        final = self.context.createCGImage(tempImage!, from: rect!)

        return CIImage(cgImage: final!)
    }

}
```

And now, the most strange thing, I have 30 VSFilters and when I got to 13(switching one by one by UIButton) I got error "Out of Buffer", this one:

```
kCMSampleBufferDroppedFrameReason_OutOfBuffers
```

What I tested:

- I changed vsFilters order in filters array inside FilterManager singleton - same
- I tried switch from first to 12 one by one, then go back - works, but after I switched to 13tn(of 30th from 0) - bug

Looks like it can handle only 12 VSFIlter objects, like if it retains them somehow or maybe it's related to threading, I don't know.

This app made for iOs devices, tested on iPhone X iOs 13.3.1
This is video editor app to apply different effects to both live stream from camera and video files from camera roll

Maybe someone has experience with this?

Have a great day

Best, Victor

Edit 1. If I reinit cameraController(AVCaptureSession. input/output devices) it works but this is ugly option and it adds lag when switching filters

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I finally won this battle. In case some one else get this "OutOfBuffer" problem, here is my solution

As I figured out, CIFilter grabs CVPixelBuffer and don't release it while filtering images. It's kinda creates one huge buffer, I guess. Strange thing: it don't create memory leak, so I guess it grabs not particular buffer but creates strong reference to it. As rumors(me) say, it can handle only 12 such references.

So, my approach was to copy CVPixelBuffer and then work with it instead of buffer I got from AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate didOutput func

Here is my new code:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        if !paused {
            //print("camera controller \(id) got frame")

            if connection.output?.connection(with: .audio) == nil {
                //capture video

                connection.videoOrientation = .portrait

                // getting image
                guard let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }

                // this works!
                let copyBuffer = pixelBuffer.copy()

                // captured - is just ciimage property
                captured = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: copyBuffer)
                //remove if any

                // transform image to targer resolution
                let srcWidth = CGFloat(captured.extent.width)
                let srcHeight = CGFloat(captured.extent.height)

                let dstWidth: CGFloat = ConstantsManager.shared.k_video_width
                let dstHeight: CGFloat = ConstantsManager.shared.k_video_height

                let scaleX = dstWidth / srcWidth
                let scaleY = dstHeight / srcHeight

                var transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: scaleX, y: scaleY)
                captured = captured.transformed(by: transform).cropped(to: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: dstWidth, height: dstHeight))
                // mirror for front camera
                if front {
                    var t = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
                    t = t.translatedBy(x: -ConstantsManager.shared.k_video_width, y: 0)
                    captured = captured.transformed(by: t)
                }

                // video capture logic
                let writable = canWrite()

                if writable,
                    sessionAtSourceTime == nil {
                    sessionAtSourceTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
                    videoWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: sessionAtSourceTime!)
                }

                if writable, (videoWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {
                    videoWriterInput.append(sampleBuffer)
                }

                self.captured = FilterManager.shared.applyFilterForCamera(inputImage: self.captured)

                // current frame in case user wants to save image as photo
                self.capturedPhoto = captured

                // sent frame to Camcoder view controller
                self.delegate?.didCapturedFrame(frame: captured)
            } else {
                // capture sound
                let writable = canWrite()
                if writable, (audioWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {
                    //print("write audio buffer")
                    audioWriterInput?.append(sampleBuffer)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // paused
            //print("paused camera controller \(id)")
        }
    }
```

and there is func to copy buffer:

```
func copy() -> CVPixelBuffer {
        precondition(CFGetTypeID(self) == CVPixelBufferGetTypeID(), "copy() cannot be called on a non-CVPixelBuffer")

        var _copy : CVPixelBuffer?
        CVPixelBufferCreate(
            kCFAllocatorDefault,
            CVPixelBufferGetWidth(self),
            CVPixelBufferGetHeight(self),
            CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(self),
            nil,
            &_copy)

        guard let copy = _copy else { fatalError() }

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(self, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.readOnly)
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(copy, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))


        let copyBaseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(copy)
        let currBaseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(self)

        print("copy data size: \(CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(copy))")
        print("self data size: \(CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(self))")

        memcpy(copyBaseAddress, currBaseAddress, CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(copy))
        //memcpy(copyBaseAddress, currBaseAddress, CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(self) * 2)

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(copy, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(self, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.readOnly)


        return copy
    }
```

I used it as extension

I hope, this will help anyone with similar problem

Best, Victor

Comment: Thank you so much! I had the same problem when using AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizerDelegate(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedataoutputsynchronizerdelegate). It provides 2 pixel buffers for video and depth frames and I made sure to release them immediately before using them for processing in another view controller. That solved the issue I was facing!